# Send an email, if a cell in Excel has a specific date

Tags: excel, vba

1. Excel will have a list of different dates and receivers' email ids across each date.
2. If the cell has a specific date, an auto-email will be sent to the email ids mentioned across it.
3. The mail is to be sent through Outlook.

Comment: Sharing your code attempt is a good way to attract other users who want to help you in improving it. We are not a code4free community.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty general question but lets first talk about the possible approach.
1. Get date from cells in a loop
2. If date matches with a particular date, call a sub to send mail
3. Pass corresponding mail ids in parameter (of the sendMail method) to send mail

I won't be able to give you exact code but here is roughly how it will be:

```
For i = 1 to n
  strDate = workbooks.worksheet("Sheet1").cells(i,1)
  emailList = workbooks.worksheet("Sheet1").cells(i,2)
  if (strDate=expectedDate) then
     call sendMail(emailList)
  end if
Next


Public function sendMail(emailList)

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With


 On Error GoTo err


'Now open a new mail

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = emailList
.CC = ""
.Subject = "test"
.Body = "the content of the mail"
End With
On Error GoTo 0


'set nothing to the objects created
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

'Now set the application properties back to true
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
MsgBox ("Email has been Sent Successfully")
Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox err.Description
End function
```